# Why wont input box shrink more?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-grid

I made a search box with CSS grid that shrinks when you shrink the page. But, for some reason, it won't shrink as much as it I think it should be able to.

Here is how it looks fully extended
[image]
Here is how it looks when the page is shrunk.
[image]

Navbar.css

```
* {
    margin: 0;
} 

ul {
    list-style: none; 
    display: flex;
} 

a {
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #fff;
} 

.homeBtn {
    height: 55px; 
    text-align: center; 
    justify-content: center; 
    padding: auto; 

}

#nav-bar {
    background-color: #888888;
    overflow: hidden;
} 

.container {
    display: grid; 
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 6fr 1fr;
    align-items: center;
} 

ul li a {
    padding: 1.6rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.form-control {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
    border-color: rgb(133, 133, 133);  
    border-top-left-radius: 5px !important;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px !important; 
    height: 38px; 
    width: 90%;
    flex: auto;
    border: none; 
    padding-left: 10px;  
    justify-content: center;
}   

.homeBtn {
    background-color: #00ce7f;
} 

.search {
  padding-left: 10px; 
}
.btn { 
    padding-right: 10px; 
} 

.ugh-buttons {
margin-right: 10px;
}

.icon-btn {
    height: 40px; 
    width: 40px; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
    background-color: #00ce7f;
    color: white; 
    border: none; 
    padding-left: 5px;
}

button:active {
    outline: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important; 
    background-color: rgb(111, 0, 255);
} 

button:active {
    outline: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important; 
    background-color: rgb(111, 0, 255);
} 

button:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important; 
}

button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
} 

.searchBtn {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #00ce7f;
    height: 38px; 
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; 
    width: 40px;   
    border: none;  
    font-weight: bold;
}       

.buttons {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #00ce7f;
    height: 38px; 
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; 
    border-top-left-radius: 5px; 
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; 
   text-align: center;
    width: 40px;   
    border: none; 
    font-size: large; 
    font-weight: bold;
}
 
[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

input {
    outline: none;
}
```

Navbar.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BsFillPersonFill } from 'react-icons/bs';
import { FiMail } from 'react-icons/fi';
import { FaPlus, FaSearch } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { AiTwotoneBell } from 'react-icons/ai';
import './navbar.css';
function Navbar() {
  return (
<nav id="nav-bar">
  <div className="container">
    <h2 className="homeBtn">VIZZEY</h2> 
    <div className="search">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search" className="form-control" />
    <button className="searchBtn">o</button>
    </div>
    <ul className="ugh-buttons">
      <li className="btn">
      <button className="icon-btn">lol</button>
      </li>
      <li className="btn">
      <button className="icon-btn">lol</button>
      </li>
      <li className="btn">
      <button className="icon-btn">lol</button>
      </li>
      <li className="btn">
        <button className="icon-btn">lol</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
  )
}
export default Navbar;
```

How do I make the search bar shrink enough to keep the button intact on the side?

Comment: your posted css doesn't style xour html as in your picture.i can not reproduce your page

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for ?
Button is always stayed inside the input field

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

body{
 margin:3rem;
}
.parentContainer{
  position:relative;
  margin:2rem;
}
input[type="text"]{
  height:30px;
  width:100%;  
  padding-right:2rem;
}

button{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  height:30px;
  padding:.2rem;  
  background-color:transparent;
  cursor:pointer;
  border:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentContainer">
  <input type="text" />
  <button>&#x1F50D;</button>
</div>
```